# Let $p$ be a prime number. How I can simplify this expression

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

My **question** is: Let $p$ be a prime number. How I can simplify this expression:

$$z=2∑_{j=0}^{2^{p-3}}C_{2^{p-2}}^{2j}2^{2^{p-2}-2j} 3^{j}$$ where $C_{2^{p-2}}^{2j}=((2^{p-2}!)/((2j)!(2^{p-2}-2j)!))$

Comment: Where does it come from? It helps if you motivate us!

Comment: @TonyK: I found it as this as a home work.

Comment: Looks like an expression that is intended to scare you, but probably quite easy because everything goes away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Due to the binominal theorem we have:
$$
\left(2+\sqrt3\right)^{2^{p-2}}=\frac{z}{2}+{∑_{j=0}^{2^{p-3}-1}C_{2^{p-2}}^{2j+1}2^{2^{p-2}-2j-1} \left(\sqrt{3}\right)^{2j+1}}
$$
And:
$$
\left(2-\sqrt3\right)^{2^{p-2}}=\frac{z}{2}-{∑_{j=0}^{2^{p-3}-1}C_{2^{p-2}}^{2j+1}2^{2^{p-2}-2j-1} \left(\sqrt{3}\right)^{2j+1}}
$$
Combining these results leads to an explicit expression for $z$.